# Wordpress wp_options table corrupts periodically

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress, corrupt

I have a problem about `wp_options` table.
Firstly my `wp_options` table was corrupted. I'm getting the following error:

> "wp_options.MYD' not found (Errcode: 2 "No such file or directory")

because of this I can't repair that table.

My solutions was restoring that table from previous backup. It worked for 30min or 1 hour, after that it corrupted again and I am getting same error (errcode:2) again.

I disabled plugins that gives PHP errors. I tried again and again. Always same table corrupts.

Now I don't get any PHP errors. WordPress gives DB connection error naturally. Why this table corrupts periodically? What could cause this?

Comment: It is clear that your `mysqld` database server software is unstable. Do you control the machine upon which it runs? If so, check for stuff like the disks filling up or, maybe, wearing out and getting lots of errors.  If you don't control that machine (if it's operated by a hosting provider or IT department for example) open top-priority service ticket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can switch the database engine to InnoDB.

It doesn't corrupt on server restarts or crashes, and is more stable in general.

Wordpress should still work fine, you just need to alter your current table to `engine=InnoDB`.